# what are the ways to protect excel sheet 2010 template from user modification?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I am having excel template with fields(Column) and few of the column are colored.I want to restrict use from manipulating the excel template,but also the user can insert data into the template and edit the inserted data.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Lock-or-unlock-specific-areas-of-a-protected-worksheet-bdb8252f-d605-45cb-9712-137925867ad4?ui=en-US&rs=en-AU&ad=AU) see if it'll help you.

Comment: @nitesh.kodle123 Did the page solved your problem?

Comment: @CharlieRB Thanks for responding.Yes I tried using worksheet and workbook protect utilities,but was not able to fulfill my scenario.But the link shared by Sdghasemi was very helpfull.

Comment: @Sdghasemi Thanks for responding.Yes it was very helpful.

Comment: So, did what @Sdghasemi shared solve your problem? Or are you still looking for a solution?

Comment: @Sdghasemi I got the solution.

Comment: @nitesh.kodle123 Your welcome :) in order to help others in future write an answer for your question and describe what u have done!